# MySQL Function - getting bigger value using IF statement

Tags: mysql, function

I want to create a function in MySql and I'm trying to return the value (out of two values) which is bigger.
In my code these values are in variables X and Y, here is my code:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION getMaxDistanceById(id int(11))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE X INT DEFAULT 0;        
DECLARE Y INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT MAX(distance) INTO X FROM trainings WHERE user_id = id;
SELECT MAX(trainings.distance) INTO Y FROM trainings INNER JOIN attendings ON trainings.tid = attendings.tid WHERE attendings.uid = id;
IF X <= Y THEN
    SET X = Y;
RETURN X;
END
;;
```

The error I'm getting while executing this statement in phpMyAdmin is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12
```

I hope that someone knows the right way to do that and I'll be very thankful for sharing the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `END IF`.

The entire thing can be simplified into a single expression using `GREATEST` (which returns the largest of its arguments).

```
RETURN GREATEST(
    (SELECT MAX(distance) FROM trainings WHERE user_id = id),
    (SELECT MAX(trainings.distance) FROM trainings INNER JOIN attendings ON trainings.tid = attendings.tid WHERE attendings.uid = id)
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, adding END IF solved the problem, also the simplified expression works perfectly! :)